# Correlation Function

Tags: r, correlation

I wrote a function that takes a directory of data files and a threshold for complete cases and calculates the correlation between two variables(sulfate and nitrate) on the second and third column of the data set,for monitor locations where the  number of completely observed cases is greater than the threshold.
My function returns a warning message:

```
in if(n>0){:
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.
```

Please been trying to fix this to no avail. I am very new to programming. Would appreciate any helpful solution.

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
    files <- list.files(directory,full.names = TRUE)
    p <- data.frame()
    for (i in 1:332) {
        p <- rbind(p,read.csv(files[i]))
        r <- c(p[,2])
        s <- c(p[,3])
        n <- p[! is.na(p[,])]
        if (n > threshold) { 
            cor(r,s)
        } else {
            return(0)
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: you are getting error b/c `n` represents more than one value. Maybe you want `length(n) > threshold`?

Comment: This is coursera homework.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion,i tried editing length but it returns Null. Its an assignment i m stuck at this point, still trying to sort it. Thanks.